# I have an error about installation Adafruit PWM servo library on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-20.04, adafruit

I'm an high school student and I'm new to developing projects. I have jetson nano and connect servo motors via PCA9685 .Also my OS is ubuntu 20.04. I have a C++ code so I try to install Adafruit libraries from [github repo](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-PWM-Servo-Driver-Library.git).

Here is my terminal output:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-PWM-Servo-Driver-Library.git
Cloning into 'Adafruit-PWM-Servo-Driver-Library'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 703, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (21/21), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (19/19), done.
remote: Total 703 (delta 5), reused 9 (delta 2), pack-reused 682
Receiving objects: 100% (703/703), 249.72 KiB | 916.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (384/384), done.

$ cd Adafruit-PWM-Servo-Driver-Library
~/Adafruit-PWM-Servo-Driver-Library

$ sudo make install 
make: *** No rule to make target 'install'.  Stop.
```

And this is the c++ code;

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_PWMServoDriver.h>

Adafruit_PWMServoDriver pwm = Adafruit_PWMServoDriver();

void setup() {
  pwm.begin();
  pwm.setPWMFreq(60);
}

void loop() {
  pwm.setPWM(0, 0, 150);
  delay(1000); 
  
 pwm.setPWM(1,0,600);
 delay(1000);
}
```

Firtly I run "sudo make install command"  in home directory and I got the same error.I have been told to run it in related directory as I showed here. I did this project with python before and that time I need to do this with c++. Can you help me to fix it or do you have any library suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: The repo does not include a `Makefile` and sort of looks like you're supposed to just add `h` and `cpp` files to your project.

Comment: How can I do this? Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I would follow the [official tutorial](https://learn.adafruit.com/16-channel-pwm-servo-driver/using-the-adafruit-library) which recommends installing via arduino library manager.